# Java: jar files generated through eclipse dont run. Whats could the issue be?

Tags: html, eclipse, jar, java

Other jars run fine. The source files compile and work correctly, and I am using a JFrame as the GUI to be displayed.

The only thing I have selected in the wizard is "export java source files and resources".

When I try the same with "export all output folders for checked projects" AND "export java source files and resources" checked. It says "JAR finished export with warnings"

```
error:
Problem writing ninja1.0/bin/base.html
Duplicate entry: base.html
```

I have base.html in both the src and bin folders (don't see anything wrong with that <.<). And it isn't duplicated anywhere else in the project. What could the problem possibly be...?

Comment: I believe you need an option more like 'Export as **runnable** Jar'.  Test the Jar on the command line with `java -jar the.jar` - report the output.

Comment: oh snap, only now notice that the expandable java node in the export wizard has "Runnable JAR File" as an option. Thanks a lot, it works. :-) Post your answer and ill pick it as best for your point gathering pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need an option more like 'Export as **runnable** Jar'.